# Can not get my function to accept the PHP mysqli query array

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to make a table where some cells shall have info according to an data base. If I do like this it works:

```
$date->modify('-1 day');
for ($x = 1; $x <=7; $x++) {
    $date->modify('+1 day');
    $b = true;
    echo "<tr>",  PHP_EOL;
    echo "<td id='dag".$x."0' class='dag'>v".$date->format('W-D j/n')."</td>",  PHP_EOL;
//*********** to function
    foreach($t_tider as $field){
        if ($field['datum'] == $date->format('Y-m-d') && $field['slot'] == 1){
            echo "<td id='dag".$x."1'><div class='bokad'>".$field['lgh_nr']."-".$field['last_name']."</div></td>",  PHP_EOL;
            $b = false;
            }
        }
//***********
    if($b) {
            echo "<td id='dag".$x."1'>Ledig</td>",  PHP_EOL;
            }
```

// and so on,  7 rows and 5 columns and a header row
// but if I try to make a function of it it don’t recognize the array, only the first post are there.

```
function checkBokn($st, $tid, $d, $i){
foreach($st as $field){
    if ($d->format('Y-m-d') == $field['datum'] && $field['slot'] == $tid){
        echo "<td id='dag".$i.$tid."'><div class='bokad'>".$field['lgh_nr']."-".$field['last_name']."</div></td>",  PHP_EOL;
        return $bol = false;
        }
// solved
/*  else {
        return $bol = true;
        } */
    }
return $bol = true; //moved
}

$b = checkBokn($t_tider, 2, $date, $x);
```

the `$t_tider` are an `mysqli` query.

BTW 
Are there some way to add and subtract dates in `strftime()`, like on `$date->modify('+1 day');` or make `$date` show days in another language than English?

Comment: I'd put some print_r statements in, such as inside the function, to double check that what is passing to function, is exactly what I thought was passing to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Well I "solved" it, the else return breaks the loop, feeling stupid. Had to be after the loop.